# How to set color of NSView in Cocoa App using Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview

I used to develop for iOS and I do not understand why I can't easily change background color of `NSView`s inside my main view.

Let's say I have a view controller with a main view in it. In this view I've added 3 custom views, I've set their constraints to fit the main view.

I've created 3 outlets to my view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var topView: NSView!
@IBOutlet weak var leftView: NSView!
@IBOutlet weak var rightView: NSView!
```

[image: 3 views in IB]

After that, I'm trying to set the background of these views and can't do this. I don't see any color changes when I run the app.

Here is the code I've added to show colors for my custom views:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.wantsLayer = true

        self.topView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
        self.rightView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
        self.leftView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.yellow.cgColor
    }
```

And it shows nothing (no background color on my views):

[image: no background color on views]

I can't understand why this code doesn't work. Why it is so hard to set the color of an `NSView` (while it is so easy in iOS development)? I'm using Xcode 8 and writing code using Swift 3.

Comment: That's not a good way of changing the background color of the underlying view.  Depending on the background color and the text color, the text of an NSTextField label could blur.

Comment: What's the good way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `wantsLayer` to `true` for your **subviews**, not for your superview.

```
self.topView.wantsLayer = true
self.rightView.wantsLayer = true
self.leftView.wantsLayer = true
```

Comment: Oh my god, so easy. Thanks, in 10 minutes i will accept this as the right answer. BTW, Is it the only way to change color of NSViews?

Comment: @Adelmaer This is the easiest way to do it. You can write an extension to do this for you with one line. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890144/setting-backgroundcolor-of-custom-nsview).

Comment: Oh great link, thanks, btw it is strange, but when i've implemented the extension solution for Swift 3 and pressed run, it showed me colors not on every run. so i've added DispatchQueue.main.async to set and after that it started to show colors on every run.

Answer (score 1):

The layer approach is convenient, but it will create a terrible issue unless you have a very dark background again a bright text color (or vice versa...  I don't remember which is which any more.) for an NSTextField label.  Unlike Cocoa Touch, which lets you change the background color of a UIView object, unfortunately, you have to subclass NSView in Cocoa for certainty like the following.

```
import Cocoa

class RedView: NSView {
    override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        let color = NSColor.red
        color.set()
        NSRectFill(rect)
    }
}
```

Then set the class name according to whatever you call your subclass (RedView here) under the identity inspector of the interface builder.  If you want to change the background color programatically, wire up the view object.  Then do something like the following.

```
import Cocoa

class MyView: NSView {
    // MARK: - Variables
    var backgroundColor = NSColor()

    // MARK: - Draw
    override func draw(_ rect:NSRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        backgroundColor.set()
        NSRectFill(rect)
    }

    // MARK: - Method
    func changeBackgroundColor(color: NSColor) {
        backgroundColor = color
        setNeedsDisplay(self.bounds)
    }
}
```

You can then call changeBackgroundColor from the view controller like...

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: MyView!
myView.changeBackgroundColor(color: NSColor.green)
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll try your approach too!