# How to add dark mode color to NSView layer color

Tags: swift, macos

I've added a light mode color and a dark mode colour and set the color like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    titleLabel.textColor = .CP2
    view.wantsLayer = true
    view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.myColor.cgColor
}
```

[image]

Regardless of dark mode and light mode, the color is always the Any Appearance color.

Comment: does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53694368/20452635

Comment: Have you tried adding a light mode color?